# Promise.all() - How to resolve() without returning undefined or value

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to use `Promise.all()` to check if a value is in an array. My problem is when the value is not found in the array, the promise returns `undefined`, but I would like to only have the values that was found in my array.

```
var array = [1,5,10];
var values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var foundValues = [];

values.forEach(function(value) {
    foundValues.push(isInArray(array, value));
});

Promise.all(foundValues).then(function(values) {
    console.log(values) // [1, undefined, undefined, undefined, 5, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 10 ]
});

function isInArray(array, value) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (array.indexOf(value) > -1) {
            resolve(value); //here the value is returned
        } else {
            resolve(); //here undefined is returned
        }
    });
};
```

**Edit:** The question is not really about finding a value in an array, I just choose this simple example to illustrate my question.

Comment: You realize there are far better ways to check if a value is in an array, right?

Comment: I assume you are using this as an example for more complex async code, but what is the real question? If you don't find any values, whats wrong with `resolve()` since you have nothing to resolve?

Comment: `values = values.filter(x => typeof x !== 'undefined')`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be possible. I would file it away as a "sane default", because it is very easy to opt-in to the behavior you want, but the inverse isn't true.

E.g.:

```
Promise.all(foundValues)
  .then(function(values) {
     return values.filter(function(value) { return typeof value !== 'undefined';});
  })
  .then(function(values) {
    console.log(values) // [1, 5, 10]
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it's not possible to make `Promise.all` to do that.
There is no feature like that in JavaScript `Promise`. A `Promise` cannot `resolve` or `reject` without a value.

Can this code answer your question: `values.filter(value => value !== undefined);`(Chrome, Opera, Safari, Firefox(in-use version), and IE 9+ support [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).)?