# Can an async function return undefined instead of a Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise

I am working on an app using nodejs. I am making multiple HTTP requests with an async function and axios library. However I do not always want to return the fetched data from my http request, only if a certain condition is met.

Like so.

```js
const getFooHTTP = async (id) => {
let response = await axios.get(url);

if (condition){
//I only want to return the response here
return response;
}

//Here i do not want to return the response
}
```

Then I am getting all the promises returned in an array with `Promise.all()`

```js
const getAllData = async() => {
let dataArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++){
const data = getFooHTTP(i);
dataArray.push(data)
}
const someData = await Promise.all(dataArray);
return someData ;
}
```

Then I get all the data

```js
getAllData().then(data => {
//Here is the problem, here I get a bunch of undefined in my data array
console.log(data);
})
```

Here is my problem, when I get the returned data from `getAllData`, there is some undefined element because at the first function in the beginning (`getFooHTTP`) was returning nothing. My question is how can I return promises conditionally, so I don't get undefined promises returned even If the async function have no return statement.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing undefined values from Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28607451/removing-undefined-values-from-array) and [Promise.all() - How to resolve() without returning undefined or value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35413572/promise-all-how-to-resolve-without-returning-undefined-or-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `async` function will *always* return a Promise, no matter what. If you explicitly return a non-Promise even if there are no `await`s before it, it will be automatically wrapped in a Promise before returning (eg `return undefined` will turn into something like `return Promise.resolve(undefined)`).

```js
const prom = (async () => {
  return undefined;
})();

// Even though it returned undefined, it's still a Promise:
console.log(typeof prom.then);
```

If you don't want to return values that don't fulfill `condition`, `filter` the `Promise.all` before returning it:

```
const getFooHTTP = async (id) => {
  let response = await axios.get(url);
  if (condition){
    //I only want to return the response here
    return response;
  }
  //Here i do not want to return the response
  return undefined;
  // or, have no return statement at all
};
```

and

```
const getAllData = async() => {
  let dataArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++){
    const data = getFooHTTP(i);
    dataArray.push(data)
  }
  const someData = (await Promise.all(dataArray))
      .filter(val => val !== undefined);
  return someData ;
};
```

Though, this relies on all of the Promises that `getFooHTTP` resolves to returning non-`undefined` values.